# How to connect to PostgreSQL DB with PHP?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, yii2

As you can already see in the title I want to connect to a PostgreSQL Database I created on a server using PHP and Yii2. Unfortunately I am a total novice when it comes to this kind of job and I have never done it before so I have several questions that I hope some of you can answer.

1. I am using Yii2 basic and in the config directory there is a `db.php` file containing the following code:

```
    return [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=my1DB',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ];
```

Is the code actually OK? Instead of localhost I will be using the host IP of course. The db `my1DB` is actually created and already contains a relation named `countries`.

2. I have Yii2 basic installed on my client. Now my question is, do I need to install it on the server as well? It may be a dumb question and I am truly sorry if it is, but I am not sure if I am understanding it all correctly. So, does the `db.php` file need to be on the server? Or is it OK if it is simply installed on my client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The db.php would need to be on server side where the PHP is running at, in case the PostgreSQL server is running on the same server that PHP is, you can leave it as localhost and it should work fine, just make sure the credentials and db name exist.